# Microchip Studio, porting attiny85 usi uart code to attiny84 not working

Tags: uart, serial, attiny85

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help me with this. So I got a copy of some code that works pretty well just using the USI as a UART for the attiny85. At the default 8 MHz internal oscillator, divide by 8, 1 MHz clock, I can get a good serial output at 2400 baud, 8n1. If I remove the divide fuse and bring the clock up to 8 MHz, I get a good 9600 baud, 8n1 serial output. Below is that working code:

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL // Setting micro to 1MHz
 
 
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
 
 
// #define BAUDRATE            9600 // if running at 8 MHz
#define BAUDRATE            2400    // if running at 1 MHz
#define STOPBITS            1
 
 
extern uint8_t usiserial_send_available();
extern void usiserial_send_byte(uint8_t data);
 
 
// If bit width in cpu cycles is greater than 255 then  divide by 8 to fit in timer
// Calculate prescaler setting
#define CYCLES_PER_BIT       ( (F_CPU) / (BAUDRATE) )
#if (CYCLES_PER_BIT > 255)
#define DIVISOR             8
#define CLOCKSELECT         2
#else
#define DIVISOR             1
#define CLOCKSELECT         1
#endif
#define FULL_BIT_TICKS      ( (CYCLES_PER_BIT) / (DIVISOR) )
 
 
// USISerial send state variable
enum USISERIAL_SEND_STATE { AVAILABLE, FIRST, SECOND };
static volatile uint8_t usiserial_send_state = AVAILABLE;
 
 
static inline uint8_t usiserial_send_get_state(void) {
    return usiserial_send_state;
}
 
 
static inline void usiserial_send_set_state(enum USISERIAL_SEND_STATE state) {
    usiserial_send_state=state;
}
 
 
uint8_t usiserial_send_available() {
    return usiserial_send_get_state() == AVAILABLE;
}
 
 
// Transmit data persistent between USI OVF interrupts
static volatile uint8_t usiserial_tx_data;
 
 
static inline uint8_t usiserial_get_tx_data(void) {
    return usiserial_tx_data;
}
 
 
static inline void usiserial_set_tx_data(uint8_t tx_data) {
    usiserial_tx_data = tx_data;
}
 
 
static uint8_t reverse_byte (uint8_t x) {
    x = ((x >> 1) & 0x55) | ((x << 1) & 0xaa);
    x = ((x >> 2) & 0x33) | ((x << 2) & 0xcc);
    x = ((x >> 4) & 0x0f) | ((x << 4) & 0xf0);
    return x;
}
 
 
void usiserial_send_byte(uint8_t data)
{
    while (usiserial_send_get_state() != AVAILABLE) {
        // Spin until we finish sending previous packet
    };
    
    usiserial_send_set_state(FIRST);
    usiserial_set_tx_data(reverse_byte(data));
 
 
    // Configure Timer0
    TCCR0A = 2<<WGM00;                      // CTC mode
    TCCR0B = CLOCKSELECT;                   // Set prescaler to clk or clk /8
    GTCCR |= 1 << PSR0;                     // Reset prescaler
    OCR0A = FULL_BIT_TICKS;                 // Trigger every full bit width
    TCNT0 = 0;                              // Count up from 0
 
 
    // Configure USI to send high, start bit and 6 bits of data
    // Start bit (low 0x00)
    // followed by first 7 bits of serialOutput
    USIDR = 0x00 | usiserial_get_tx_data() >> 1;
    
    // Enable USI Counter OVF interrupt (USIOIE).
    // Select three wire mode to ensure USI written to PB1 (USIWM0 and USIWM1)
    // Select Timer0 Compare match as USI Clock source. (USICS0, USICS1, and USICLK)
    USICR  = (1<<USIOIE) | (0<<USIWM1) | (1<<USIWM0) | (0<<USICS1) | (1<<USICS0) | (0<<USICLK);
    DDRB  |= (1<<PB1);                        // Configure USI_DO as output.
    USISR = 1<<USIOIF | (16 - 8);             // Clear USI overflow interrupt flag and set USI counter to 8
}
 
 
// USI overflow interrupt indicates we've sent a packet
ISR (USI_OVF_vect) {
    if (usiserial_send_get_state() == FIRST) {
        usiserial_send_set_state(SECOND);
        
        // Send last 1 bit of data
        // and stop bits (high 0x7F)
        USIDR = usiserial_get_tx_data() << 7 | 0x7F;
        
        // Clear USI overflow interrupt flag (USIOIF)
        // and set USI counter to send last bit and stop bits
        USISR = 1<<USIOIF | (16 - (1 + (STOPBITS)));
    } else {
        PORTB |= 1 << PB1;              // Ensure output is high
        DDRB  |= (1<<PB1);              // Configure USI_DO as output.
        USICR = 0;                      // Disable USI.
        USISR |= 1<<USIOIF;             // clear interrupt flag
        usiserial_send_set_state(AVAILABLE);
    }
}
 
 
int main(void) {
    uint8_t i = 0;
    PORTB |= 1 << PB1;              // Ensure serial output is high
    DDRB  |= (1<<PB1);              // Configure USI_DO as output.
    USICR = 0;                      // Start with USI disabled.
    sei();                          // Enable global interrupts
    
    while (1) {
        char message1[] = "Hello World!\r\n";
        uint8_t len1 = sizeof(message1)-1;
 
 
        for (i = 0; i<len1; i++) {
            while (!usiserial_send_available()) {
                // Wait for last send to complete
            }
            usiserial_send_byte(message1[i]);
        }
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

So I wanted to try using that same code framework to do the same thing with a known good attiny84. I sanity checked myself and ran a blink type code on the attiny84 and everything worked as expected, again, using the 8 MHz clock, divide by 8, 1 MHz clock. So I copied in the exact same code as before, but I knew I had to change a couple things. I believe in the attiny84, 3-wire mode USI makes the output go to PA5 instead of the PB1 that was used on the attiny85, so I made those changes (PB1 became PA5 and DDRB became DDRA). I also changed in the resetting of the prescaler where it was GTCCR |= 1 << PSR0 on the attiny85, that it would be GTCCR |= 1 << PSR10 on the attiny84. So I made those changes and loaded the below code, but the attiny84 isn't doing anything.

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL // Setting micro to 1MHz
 
 
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
 
 
// #define BAUDRATE            9600 // if running at 8 MHz
#define BAUDRATE            2400    // if running at 1 MHz
#define STOPBITS            1
 
 
extern uint8_t usiserial_send_available();
extern void usiserial_send_byte(uint8_t data);
 
 
// If bit width in cpu cycles is greater than 255 then  divide by 8 to fit in timer
// Calculate prescaler setting
#define CYCLES_PER_BIT       ( (F_CPU) / (BAUDRATE) )
#if (CYCLES_PER_BIT > 255)
#define DIVISOR             8
#define CLOCKSELECT         2
#else
#define DIVISOR             1
#define CLOCKSELECT         1
#endif
#define FULL_BIT_TICKS      ( (CYCLES_PER_BIT) / (DIVISOR) )
 
 
// USISerial send state variable
enum USISERIAL_SEND_STATE { AVAILABLE, FIRST, SECOND };
static volatile uint8_t usiserial_send_state = AVAILABLE;
 
 
static inline uint8_t usiserial_send_get_state(void) {
    return usiserial_send_state;
}
 
 
static inline void usiserial_send_set_state(enum USISERIAL_SEND_STATE state) {
    usiserial_send_state=state;
}
 
 
uint8_t usiserial_send_available() {
    return usiserial_send_get_state() == AVAILABLE;
}
 
 
// Transmit data persistent between USI OVF interrupts
static volatile uint8_t usiserial_tx_data;
 
 
static inline uint8_t usiserial_get_tx_data(void) {
    return usiserial_tx_data;
}
 
 
static inline void usiserial_set_tx_data(uint8_t tx_data) {
    usiserial_tx_data = tx_data;
}
 
 
static uint8_t reverse_byte (uint8_t x) {
    x = ((x >> 1) & 0x55) | ((x << 1) & 0xaa);
    x = ((x >> 2) & 0x33) | ((x << 2) & 0xcc);
    x = ((x >> 4) & 0x0f) | ((x << 4) & 0xf0);
    return x;
}
 
 
void usiserial_send_byte(uint8_t data)
{
    while (usiserial_send_get_state() != AVAILABLE) {
        // Spin until we finish sending previous packet
    };
    
    usiserial_send_set_state(FIRST);
    usiserial_set_tx_data(reverse_byte(data));
 
 
    // Configure Timer0
    TCCR0A = 2<<WGM00;                      // CTC mode
    TCCR0B = CLOCKSELECT;                   // Set prescaler to clk or clk /8
    GTCCR |= 1 << PSR10;                     // Reset prescaler
    OCR0A = FULL_BIT_TICKS;                 // Trigger every full bit width
    TCNT0 = 0;                              // Count up from 0
 
 
    // Configure USI to send high, start bit and 6 bits of data
    // Start bit (low 0x00)
    // followed by first 7 bits of serialOutput
    USIDR = 0x00 | usiserial_get_tx_data() >> 1;
    
    // Enable USI Counter OVF interrupt (USIOIE).
    // Select three wire mode to ensure USI written to PA5 (USIWM0 and USIWM1)
    // Select Timer0 Compare match as USI Clock source. (USICS0, USICS1, and USICLK)
    USICR  = (1<<USIOIE) | (0<<USIWM1) | (1<<USIWM0) | (0<<USICS1) | (1<<USICS0) | (0<<USICLK);
    DDRA  |= (1<<PA5);                        // Configure USI_DO as output.
    USISR = 1<<USIOIF | (16 - 8);             // Clear USI overflow interrupt flag and set USI counter to 8
}
 
 
// USI overflow interrupt indicates we've sent a packet
ISR (USI_OVF_vect) {
    if (usiserial_send_get_state() == FIRST) {
        usiserial_send_set_state(SECOND);
        
        // Send last 1 bit of data
        // and stop bits (high 0x7F)
        USIDR = usiserial_get_tx_data() << 7 | 0x7F;
        
        // Clear USI overflow interrupt flag (USIOIF)
        // and set USI counter to send last bit and stop bits
        USISR = 1<<USIOIF | (16 - (1 + (STOPBITS)));
    } else {
        PORTA |= 1 << PA5;              // Ensure output is high
        DDRA  |= (1<<PA5);              // Configure USI_DO as output.
        USICR = 0;                      // Disable USI.
        USISR |= 1<<USIOIF;             // clear interrupt flag
        usiserial_send_set_state(AVAILABLE);
    }
}
 
 
int main(void) {
    uint8_t i = 0;
    PORTA |= 1 << PA5;              // Ensure serial output is high
    DDRA  |= (1<<PA5);              // Configure USI_DO as output.
    USICR = 0;                      // Start with USI disabled.
    sei();                          // Enable global interrupts
    
    while (1) {
        char message1[] = "Hello World!\r\n";
        uint8_t len1 = sizeof(message1)-1;
 
 
        for (i = 0; i<len1; i++) {
            while (!usiserial_send_available()) {
                // Wait for last send to complete
            }
            usiserial_send_byte(message1[i]);
        }
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: Could you clarify on "Isn't doing anything"? The code changes should be sufficient for both MCUs to behave the same.

Comment: I get no output on the attiny84 TX/DO pin, PA5, when using the same USB to serial device I did, when using the attiny85 on its TX/DO pin, PB1. Both are using 1 MHz internal oscillators and both are at 2400 baud, 8n1.

I know, I am just as puzzled as you.

Comment: Can you probe with a logic analyser or oscilloscope. The internal oscillator is typically only calibrated to 10%, so could be that the baud rate is out.

Answer (score 0):

Per Tom Carpenter, it does appear the internal oscillator was just a tad too far out for the serial to work. I added a crystal to the attiny84 and then it all of a sudden came to life. I tried another attiny84 and it's internal oscillator was better equipped, as it didn't need an external oscillator.

Comment: Have a look at the datasheet regarding the OSCCAL register.  It lets you tune the internal oscillator for an individual chip to get a more accurate frequency.  It's very useful for one-off projects, and often means you don't need an external oscillator.